# Run a script when there is no audio

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows, visual-studio-2010

i am trying to download a long tutorial from a website containing a lot of links, and I would like to do that automatically.

I need to create a script that listen to audio, if the program does not hear anything after 5 sec then it should click on the next button (I know how to simulate a click).

I have never worked with audio, could you please advice me an api/function that would listen to the 
sound and return a value (true, false) or anything like that when it does not hear anything.

Many thanks

Comment: What's the connection between downloading something and silence?

Answer (score 0):

This is recording: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff827802.aspx

And then you would have to know the exact WaveFormat of the recorded sound. If you've got the exact WaveFormat (e.g. 16 bit pcm mono), you could iterate through , check whether it is within a specific range. If all of the sample is for example smaller than 0.1 it is silence. If not... click.

Comment: would it be possible to use system audio instead of the microphone ? regarding the itereation part of your answer, I didn't understand the 0.1, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Then you're looking for this, which records system audio:
`waveIn = new WasapiLoopbackCapture();
waveIn.DataAvailable += InputBufferToFileCallback;    
waveIn.StartRecording();`. It works on windows 7.

Comment: @Lior should probably mention that that requires [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/documentation)

Answer (score 0):

you want to download the tutorial and further information of a website? why write a script for that by hand? take a look at existing tools. e.g. http://pagenest.com/
Don't know if that fits your requirement but there are quite some tools for downloading website information
BR